# Apache Spark 2.4.0, AWS EMR, Spark Redshift and User class threw exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, spark-redshift

I use Apache Spark 2.4.0, AWS EMR and Spark Redshift and right now faced the following error during reading Redshift table in Spark DataFrame:

```
User class threw exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceUtils$$anonfun$verifySchema$1.apply(DataSourceUtils.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceUtils$$anonfun$verifySchema$1.apply(DataSourceUtils.scala:47)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.foreach(StructType.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceUtils$.verifySchema(DataSourceUtils.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceUtils$.verifyReadSchema(DataSourceUtils.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:400)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
        at com.databricks.spark.redshift.RedshiftRelation.buildScan(RedshiftRelation.scala:168)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$10.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:293)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$10.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:293)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$pruneFilterProject$1.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:326)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$pruneFilterProject$1.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:325)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy.pruneFilterProjectRaw(DataSourceStrategy.scala:403)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy.pruneFilterProject(DataSourceStrategy.scala:321)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:63)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:435)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:441)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1334)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:67)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:435)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:441)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3360)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2545)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2759)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:255)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:292)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:746)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:705)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:714)
```

Versions:

```
spark-redshift_2.11:3.0.0-preview1
apache.spark 2.11:2.0.4
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix this issue?

Comment: Looks like a version mismatch, but are you aware that Spark Redshift is no longer supported or maintained? And hasn't been in a long time.

Comment: Taking this into account, what are the options to workaround this issue?

Comment: Spark redshift connector seems outdated and it is built for old spark version. What is the use-case? For testing with small amounts of data a JDBC works well. For actual data loading probably best to write to S3 and load from there using Redshift copy command or use Firehose that automatically does that for you.

Comment: I need to join Spark DataFrames. One of them must be created based on Redshift table.

Comment: Right now I'm able to write to Redshift using CSV, but not able to read from Redshift to DataFrame

Comment: Additionaly Databricks platform (I am not affiliated with Databricks) comes with proprietary Redshift connector (continuation of Spark Redshift).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55704871/spark-2-4-0-dependencies-to-write-to-aws-redshift
hope my post can be helpful for you, I reckon it is a dependencies issue

Comment: @Vzzarr thanks for your comment but unfortunately the version `spark-redshift_2.10:2.0.0` that you use doesn't support CSV as temp format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazon.redshift/redshift-jdbc42-no-awssdk instead, then create a table using `jdbc:redshift://...`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How about the performance for reading/writing from/to Redshift of a big amount of data(like 1TB+) using pure JDBC?

Comment: At least writing is not very performant. As mentioned earlier, it is best to handle it through S3.